# Inject partial views with Backbone.js for specific route like ng-view on AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, backbone.js

I've been working with AngularJs for a while now. Although I need to get started with Backbone.js and I am getting very confused about the way this library works with routes and partial views/templates "injection". With Angular we can define on the index.html a few static components that will be common on each route/page (like the footer and navbar) and place an ng-view directive where the HTML template for each route will be "injected" in. This way we can easily maintain the common HTML(navbar and footer) for each page/route in case we need to make changes on these components (instead of changing them on each HTML file). I'm a complete newbie on Backbone.js and I've been searching for this kind of "feature"/behavior/pattern (whatever you want to call it) on Backbone but I can't seem find anything similar. Can anyone provide a simple example of partial views being injected in on a route change using Backbone?
Thanks

Comment: Write a directive, that fetch template from $http or $templateCache, and render it with backbone, and put it with jqLite or jquery .html and then $compile against current scope if needed.

Comment: The question is clear for someone who has been working with Angular.js and even clearer if he additionally has worked with Backbone.js which is not that common and probably why it's on hold.

Comment: @JaimeAgudo agreed, there is nothing unclear about it. It should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone is a much lighter framework compared to Angular. You need to write your custom logic to do this (which should be reasonably easy) but as it's pointless to reinvent the wheel I'd refer you to some extra libraries that will help you to achieve this view composition in a neat and reusable manner.

I suggest you to use and have a look at Backbone Layout Manager and its [examples](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Example-usage%20). You even have a nice [screencast](https://vimeo.com/32765088)

On each "route action handler" function you'll reuse the common views (tipycally the main layout, nav, footer etc.) and you'll change the different ones